# How to add a reference to an assembly in LINQPad to access custom types?

Tags: .net, linqpad

Is there a posibility to add a reference to an assembly in LINQPad?

I have some types in my assembly and I would like to use them in my LINQPad queries.

Answer (score 104):

Just press <kbd>F4</kbd>.

This will pop up the `Add Reference` dialog.

---

[image: Add reference to linqpad]

Comment: Do you need to add the namespace or a using statement as well?

Comment: @surfmuggle yes, in the query properties window, shown in the answer there is a second tab "Additional Namespace Imports" where the namespaces need to be added.  If you add the using statements in the query, linqpad will prompt you to move them there.

Answer (score 7):

You can also use the menu option to access the popup window to add references.

- Notice the >> arrows in menu bar. Click on it.
- Go to *Query* menu. Find *References and Properties*. Click on it.

Following is example image from LINQPad 5:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

**This doesn't apply to your case but may be helpful for others that had the same issue as me**. My issue was with a "missing" system type (`Task<T>`) since LinqPad didn't had the *using* it by default. One way to add it on LinqPad is pressing `F4` > `Namespace Imports` tabs and adding at the bottom of the list `System.Threading.Tasks` then press `Ok`.

You can also set this new list as the default for the new queries pressing `Set as default for new queries`

[image: Go by shortcut]

Other way to access this tab is by the top menu `Query` > `Namespace Imports`

[image: Go by the query menu]

Answer (score -5):

I had to do <kbd>fn</kbd> and <kbd>F4</kbd> at the same time.

Comment: the underlying system function is F4 - you just happen to require pressing "fn" on your machine to access that. This has no impact on the correct responses, above.

Comment: Sure sure sures

Comment: Who scrolls all the way to the bottom to pop a downvote on this answer? That's even more petty than me making this comment about it